# for a single click it has to read a text file till the end of text in c#

Tags: c#

i'm reading a text file and storing it to a data base.For a single click i'm able to read a single line from text file and it can be stored to a database.

But my text file is huge,so i need a method so that a single click will start reading the file and it can be stored to a database till the end of file.

this is my code:

```
Program problem = new Program();
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Billing;Integrated Security=True");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();



string line = "";
string billno = null;
string billdate = null;
string hosp_no = null;
string ip_no = null;
string name = null;
string test = null;
string ward = null;
string rad = null;
string pathNames = "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\Ex_1\\KHL.txt";

ArrayList rawData = new ArrayList();

 try
{

    StreamReader readFile = new StreamReader(pathNames);

    do
    {
        //tim

        if ((line = readFile.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            //  Console.WriteLine(line);
            if (line.Contains("RADIOLOGY"))
            {
                rawData.Add(line);
                //Console.ReadKey();
            }

        }
        else
        {
            line = null;
        }
    } while (line != null);


    int rIn = rawData.Count;

    for (int i = 0; i < rIn; i++)
    {
        con.Open();

        string[] data = (rawData[i] + "").Split('~');
        string da = "";
        hosp_no = data[1].Substring(data[1].Length - 8, 8);
        ip_no = data[2].Substring(data[1].Length - 7, 7);
        name = data[8].Replace("'", "''");
        billno = data[3];
        billdate = data[4].Substring(5, 2) + "/" + data[4].Substring(8, 2) + "/" + data[4].Substring(0, 4);
        test = data[5];
        ward = data[16];

        if (data.Length == 1 && data[0] == "") da = "Finish";
        else
        {


            cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into ex_1 values('" + hosp_no + "','" + ip_no + "','" + name.Replace(" ' ", " '' ") + "','" + billno + "','" + billdate + "','" + ward + "','" + test + "')", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            Console.Read();

        }
        //Console.WriteLine(da);
        Console.Read();
    }
}
catch (Exception f)
{
    Console.WriteLine(f.Message);
    Console.Read();
}
```

Comment: use ReadToEnd in TextReader it will read the file to the end.

Eg TextReader tr =new TextReader("Path");
string file=tr.ReadToEnd();

Answer (score 1):

You can use as follows

```
 string text = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@pathNames);
```

or

```
    // Read each line of the file into a string array. Each element 
    // of the array is one line of the file. 
    string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@pathNames);
```

Comment: error:illegal character in path. what is the solution for that

Comment: in this above method you can read the text file as a single string text.I updated the code you should have the @ for ignore the special characters.

Comment: with the above method even i have to use StreamReader()

Answer (score 0):

```
using (TextReader reader = File.OpenText(@"your file path"))
    {
        string line = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(line);
    }
```

[Reader Class, ReadToEnd Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.readtoend%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[Reader Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.IO.TextReader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[**File.OpenText Method**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.opentext.aspx/)

Comment: if the file is ReadOnly or Opened by other process it will show any exception ?